# Rails No Method Error Undefined Method 'day'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caracal

I'm trying to generate a Docx document using the Gem Caracal, everything was ok. It was generating the file with some text, but now I want to generate with my date.

contratos_controller.rb

```
class ContratosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_contrato, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :export]
  access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all
  require './lib/generate_pdf'



  # GET /contratos
  # GET /contratos.json
  def index
    @contratos = Contrato.all
  end

  # GET /contratos/1
  # GET /contratos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contratos/new
  def new
    @contrato = Contrato.new
  end

  # GET /contratos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contratos
  # POST /contratos.json
  def create
    @contrato = Contrato.new(contrato_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contrato.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contrato, notice: 'Contrato criado com sucesso' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contrato }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contrato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contratos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contratos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contrato.update(contrato_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contrato, notice: 'Contrato atualizado com sucesso' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contrato }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contrato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contratos/1
  # DELETE /contratos/1.json
  def destroy
    @contrato.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contratos_url, notice: 'Contrato excluido.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def export
    GeneratePdf::contrato(@contrato.day, @contrato.daytwo, @contrato.month, @contrato.year, @contrato.pub, @contrato.razao, @contrato.estado, @contrato.cidade, @contrato.bairro, @contrato.endereco, @contrato.cep, @contrato.cnpj, @contrato.estadual, @contrato.municipal, @contrato.telefone, @contrato.email, @contrato.responsavel, @contrato.estadotwo, @contrato.cidadetwo, @contrato.bairrotwo, @contrato.enderecotwo, @contrato.cpf, @contrato.rg, @contrato.emailtwo, @contrato.art)
    redirect_to '/contrato.pdf'
  end

  def page
    contrato = Contrato.find([:day])
    Caracal::Document.save(Rails.root.join("public", "example.docx")) do |docx|

      docx.style do
        id 'Body'
        name 'Body'
        font 'Times New Roman'
        size 24
      end

      docx.h2 'Personal Data'
      docx.p  do
        style 'Body'
        text 'Some text  '
        text contrato.day
        text ''
          #text contrato.daytwo
      end

      docx.p
    end
    path = File.join(Rails.root, "public")
    send_file(File.join(path, "example.docx"))
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contrato
      @contratos = Contrato.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contrato_params
      params.require(:contrato).permit(:day, :daytwo, :month, :year, :razao, :estado, :cidade, :bairro, :endereco, :cep, :cnpj, :estadual, :municipal, :telefone, :email, :responsavel, :estadotwo, :cidadetwo, :bairrotwo, :enderecotwo, :cpf, :rg, :emailtwo, :toll, :chemist, :mechanic, :mechanictwo, :mechanicthree, :pub, :pubtwo, :pubthree, :pubfour, :gas, :gastwo, :parking, :theather, :other, art:[])
    end
  end
```

I think that I'm setting some parameter wrong, because the file was working until I tried to map my settings. I tried to change the def page and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hey there, it's not clear which problem you faced with?

Comment: you're assuming an array of `contrato` (you're using `Contrato.where` and not `Contrato.find` ) has a `day`

Comment: I have a HTML Show page and there have "@contrato.day", "@contrato.daytwo". I want to export them to my Docx file, but I'm struggling in the controller, because I can't export them to the Docx file. I tried to change the "Users" part to contrato, and I get "Undefined variable or method 'current_contrato' "

Comment: Can you share the contratos controller code?  Is there a column for `day` and `daytwo`?

Comment: I added the entire controller.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, this is happening in the `export` action? Without a stacktrace, it's hard for us to debug, but I would guess from the error you posted that there's a reference to `current_contrato` in `GeneratePdf::contrato`, without that method being defined anywhere.